# Unable to Import, edit certain records and edit Group settings: DB Error: constraint violation

Tags: database, error, groups, smartgroups

I am unable to make certain edits to CiviCRM; unable to edit certain records and unable to edit the visibility of groups.

I think the problem is this:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ea...")

The error message is referring to a group '58' which I deleted and replaced with group "62".

How do I find the exact problem and fix it?

I'm on WP 4.5.3 with CiviCRM 4.7.9.

Here is the error message:

> Database Error Code: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`xxx_civicrm`.`civicrm_group_contact`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_group_contact_group_id` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`group_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_group` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE),
>   1452

Comment: Did you do any editing directly in the database or did you do everything through the UI? (e.g. deleting group 58)

Comment: I deleted the group from the UI and had the problem. When I tried to fix the problem, I went into the database and deleted the hidden groups. I also noticed that I had a profile for that group, so I deleted that and cleared cache in CiviCRM, but that did not solve it.  I checked the database and the group is not listed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some entries remaining in `civicrm_group_contact` which point to the deleted `civicrm_group` entry?

You can confirm this with a query to look for group contact entries which point to a missing group.

```
-- Show contacts who belong to a group that doesn't exist.
SELECT * 
  FROM civicrm_group_contact 
 WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_group);
```

If entries are found with that query, you can clear them out (or update them to point to the new group, or export those contact IDs, or ...).

```
-- Standard disclaimers apply; back up your DB before doing this!
DELETE  
  FROM civicrm_group_contact 
 WHERE group_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_group);
```

If updating, you'll want to avoid creating duplicate entries by reassigning group_id without checking for existing group additions.

Comment: The problem started when I had three groups suddenly attached as children to another group. This new parent group is displayed on a public web page, Hence the reason I deleted that group and created a new group. Now I see any time I delete a group in CiviCRM it causes this DB error. Plus every time I open Manage Group another group is added to this parent group. I did not create any parent groups, it is happening on its one. And it seems CiviCRM will not allow me to remove a parent group. Parent group is required once you have a parent group.

Comment: I used your query and there was no record of Group 58. I decided to roll the database back one week. It did not completely solve the problem, but the database is functioning.